# proof distribution Function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification

I have to show that $F=1- \exp(-x)/2$ a distribution Function on $[0, \infty)$. I become example solution, where $\lim_{x\to-\infty} F =0$. 
Can anybody explain why?
So i see $\lim_{x\to-\infty} F = 1-\lim_{x\to-\infty} \exp(-x) /2 =1-\infty$
and $F(0)=1/2$.
Thank you.

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: Press edit button and look how MathJax expressions look like. Also check if the formulas are edited correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it is written "a distribution function on $[0, \infty)$" it is supposed that $F(x)=0$ on the other part of line. So you have a function
$$
F(x)=\begin{cases}1-\frac12e^{-x}, & x\geq 0\cr 0, & x < 0. \end{cases}
$$
And $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty} F(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty} 0 =0 $.